# how can I join 3 columns on same level and get rid of duplicates

Tags: sql, ssms

I want to make the three columns on the same level. I can't do this because I gave a `grouped by`. How can we join them instead of showing duplicate rows?

```
select PartTran.PartNum,PartTran.PartDescription,
(case when Part.ProdCode like 'HSAL' then 'EHV'
when Part.ProdCode like 'MVSAL' then 'MV'
when Part.ProdCode like 'LVSAL' then 'LV'
when Part.ProdCode like 'WSAL' then 'EW'
when Part.ProdCode like 'PSAL' then 'EP'
else  'NULL'
end) as Plant,

(case UD106A.ShortChar10 when 'Box' then COUNT(UD106A.ShortChar10) else 0 end) as Barrel,
(case UD106A.ShortChar10 when 'Drum' then COUNT(UD106A.ShortChar10) else 0  end) as Drum,
(case UD106A.ShortChar10 when 'Barrel' then COUNT(UD106A.ShortChar10) else 0 end) as Barrel
from PartTran 
inner join Part on PartTran.Company = Part.Company and PartTran.PartNum = Part.PartNum and  Part.ClassID = 'Scr'
inner join vwTags on PartTran.Company = 'JCC' and vwTags.PartNum = PartTran.PartNum
inner join UD106A on vwTags.Company = UD106A.Company and vwTags.TagNum = UD106A.ShortChar01
where  PartTran.Company = 'JCC' and UD106A.ShortChar10 <> '' and Part.ProdCode in ('HSAL','LVSAL', 'MVSAL', 'WSAL', 'PSAL')  and PartTran.TranType in ('PLT-STK','STK-STK') and YEAR(PartTran.TranDate) = 2021 and TranQty > 0
group by PartTran.PartNum, PartTran.PartDescription,Part.ProdCode, UD106A.ShortChar10
order by Part.ProdCode
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you want to merge the duplicate rows into 1 row

**Sample:**

***Your result***

> ```
> LALUAMV | AL. CABLES UNARMOURED M.V   | MV | 453700 | 0    | 0 
> LALUAMV | AL. CABLES UNARMOURED M.V   | MV | 0      | 7150 | 0
> ```

***Expected***

> ```
> LALUAMV | AL. CABLES UNARMOURED M.V   | MV | 453700 | 7150 | 0
> ```

**Solution:**

> **"Remove UD106A.ShortChar10"** from group by clause and perform **"aggregate"** on Barrel, Drum and Barrel columns

***Code:***

```
select PartNum
    ,PartDescription
    ,plant
    ,sum(Barrel) as Barrel
    ,sum(drum) as drum
    ,sum(barrel1) as barrel1 
    from(
    select PartTran.PartNum,PartTran.PartDescription,
    (case when Part.ProdCode like 'HSAL' then 'EHV'
    when Part.ProdCode like 'MVSAL' then 'MV'
    when Part.ProdCode like 'LVSAL' then 'LV'
    when Part.ProdCode like 'WSAL' then 'EW'
    when Part.ProdCode like 'PSAL' then 'EP'
    else  'NULL'
    end) as Plant,
    
    (case UD106A.ShortChar10 when 'Box' then 1 else 0 end) as Barrel,
    (case UD106A.ShortChar10 when 'Drum' then 1 else 0  end) as Drum,
    (case UD106A.ShortChar10 when 'Barrel' then 1 else 0 end) as Barrel1
    from PartTran 
    inner join Part on PartTran.Company = Part.Company and PartTran.PartNum = Part.PartNum and  Part.ClassID = 'Scr'
    inner join vwTags on PartTran.Company = 'JCC' and vwTags.PartNum = PartTran.PartNum
    inner join UD106A on vwTags.Company = UD106A.Company and vwTags.TagNum = UD106A.ShortChar01
    where  PartTran.Company = 'JCC' and UD106A.ShortChar10 <> '' and Part.ProdCode in ('HSAL','LVSAL', 'MVSAL', 'WSAL', 'PSAL')  and PartTran.TranType in ('PLT-STK','STK-STK') and YEAR(PartTran.TranDate) = 2021 and TranQty > 0
    group by PartTran.PartNum, PartTran.PartDescription,Part.ProdCode,UD106A.ShortChar10
    )a
    group by  PartNum,PartDescription,plant
    order by plant
```

Please upvote if you find this answer useful.

Comment: still the problem appears   Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: Apologies, I was not able to validate the query due to object unavailability, updated the code. Please check now. Thanks